# Having issues using IFS to cut a string into an array. BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

I have tried everything I can think of to cut this into separate elements for my array but I am struggling..

Here is what I am trying to do..

(This command just rips out the IP addresses on the first element returned )

```
$ IFS=$"\n"
$ aaa=( $(netstat -nr | grep -v '^0.0.0.0' | grep -v 'eth' | grep "UGH" | sed 's/ .*//') )

$ echo "${#aaa[@]}"
1
$ echo "${aaa[0]}"
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

This shows more than one value when I am looking for the array to separate `4.4.4.4` into `${aaa[0]}` and `5.5.5.5` into `${aaa[1]}`

I have tried:

```
IFS="\n"

IFS=$"\n"

IFS=" "
```

Very confused as I have been working with arrays a lot recently and have never ran into this particular issue.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$'\n'` but why are you messing with `IFS` at all? You are getting two "words" back the normal `IFS` will split that correctly.

Comment: Just unset `IFS` and then populate array

Comment: Add output of `netstat -nr | grep -v '^0.0.0.0' | grep -v 'eth' | grep "UGH" | sed 's/ .*//'` to your question.

Comment: 'unset IFS' did the trick for me, I didn't think to unset it from a previous command. The reason I had altered to IFS=" "  was due to an array needing to keep any spaces within the filenames as was separating into separate arrays.. I had forgot to unset that!

Comment: p.s. The output of it for the person that was asking was: 4.4.4.4 5.5.5.5

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good example on how to use IFS + read -a to split a string into an array on this other stackoverflow page

[How does splitting string to array by 'read' with IFS word separator in bash generated extra space element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011867/how-does-splitting-string-to-array-by-read-with-ifs-word-separator-in-bash-gen/40012610#40012610)

netstat is deprecated, replaced by ss, so I'm not sure how to reproduce your exact problem