# How does splitting string to array by 'read' with IFS word separator in bash generated extra space element?

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

With only one character for IFS, it works fine:

```
shell@kernel: ~> l="2.4.3"; IFS="." read -a la <<< "$l"; for ((i = 0; i < ${#la[@]}; ++i)) do echo ${la[$i]}; done;
2
4
3
```

While there are two characters for IFS, extra space element generated

```
shell@kernel: ~> l="2->4->3"; IFS="->" read -a la <<< "$l"; for ((i = 0; i < ${#la[@]}; ++i)) do echo ${la[$i]}; done;
2

4

3
shell@kernel: ~> l="2..4..3"; IFS=".." read -a la <<< "$l"; for ((i = 0; i < ${#la[@]}; ++i)) do echo ${la[$i]}; done;
2

4

3
```

How can I get rid of the extra space element in the array?

Comment: `IFS="->"` specifies field separators of `"-"` and `">"`. There is *nothing* between the `"->"` in `$l` so you get an empty element.

Comment: In other words, `IFS` is not *a* field separator. It is a list of *single-character field separators*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, you can either test for an empty element before storing the value in the array, or you can deal with the empty value when you `echo` it. Frankly, its simpler to do the latter, e.g.

```
l="2->4->3"; IFS="->" read -a la <<< "$l"; \
for ((i = 0; i < ${#la[@]}; ++i)) do \
[ -n "${la[i]}" ] && echo ${la[$i]}; done
```

**Output**

```
2
4
3
```

Answer (score 1):

i would just use sed to replace the separator

see, reusing your script + sed

```
bash$ l="2->4->3"
bash$ read -a la <<< "$(echo $l | sed 's/->/ /g')"
bash$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#la[@]}; ++i)) do echo ${la[$i]}; done
2
4
3
```

but I think I would do it entirely differently

```
bash$ l="2->4->3"
bash$ for x in `echo $l | sed 's/->/ /g'`; do echo $x; done
2
4
3
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the separator `->` into a single character with:

```
l="2->4->3"

IFS="-" read -a la <<< "${l//->/-}"

printf '%s' "${la[@]}"
```

If there is the risk that the string may contain additional `-` then use a character that is improbable that will be in the string:

```
IFS="┵" read -a la <<< "${l//->/┵}"
```